# Sectioning every 3 rows in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

What I want to do is make NSFetchedResultsController section every x number of rows.

I have tried making a transient property, that will give its section based on its index like so:

```
- (NSNumber*)section
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"section"];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Animal"];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]]];
    NSArray* array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
    int order = [array indexOfObject:self];
    NSNumber *tmpValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:order / 3];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"section"];
    return tmpValue;
}
```

and made the viewcontroller refresh the section by triggering this function on every object:

```
-(void)refreshSection
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Animal"];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]]];
    NSArray* array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
    int order = [array indexOfObject:self];
   [self setSection:[NSNumber numberWithInt:order / 3]];
}
```

This solution works but is not efficient with large sets of objects.

Basically, what I want to achieve is this:

section 0:
a
b
d
section 1:
e

If I added c :

section 0:
a
b
c
section 1:
d
e

Is there any other more elegant way to do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously performance is going to be negatively affected if you do a fetch inside a transient property.

Dont' worry about this transient property. Instead, in the method numberOfSection, just return the number of objects divided by 3 rounded up.

And for number of rows in section, just return 3 but keep in mind the last section will be the remainder of the number of objects divided by 3.

When you add an object, remember to update the table and those methods will be called again.

Comment: Your method works, in the case of reloading the table view whenever any change happens, but if I want to animate the addition or deletion using update blocks, it would be very hard to translate indexpathes between the fetchedresultscontroller and the table view, and I will also have to manage the insertion and deletion of sections, since from the fetchedresultscontroller's prespective there is only one section. thats why I opted for a solution that would come directly from the fetched controller.

Comment: You said it would be very hard, not impossible? Sometimes when you have peculiar requirements, you need peculiar solutions, even if its not elegant. If performance is a must, then there isn't much choice.